# Finite right-triple convex sets in planes

Tags: discrete-geometry, convexity, computer-algebra

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We say that $\mathcal{S}$ is *right-angle convex*, if for any two distinct points $P,Q\in \mathcal{S}$ there always exists another point $R\in \mathcal{S}$ such that the triangle formed by $P,Q$ and $R$ is a right triangle.

Examples of finite and infinite right-triangle convex sets $\mathcal{S}$ can be found in this paper (http://tzamfirescu.tricube.de/TZamfirescu-212.pdf). Instead of elementary geometric argument, one can also use computational algebra approach to classify right-triangle convex sets with a small number of points.

[[image: <span class=]$\mathcal{S}=\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ on one circle" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJtwe.png)

**Question 1**: Suppose that $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is finite and any three points in $\mathcal{S}$ are NOT collinear.
If $\mathcal{S}$ is large enough, is it true that the points of $\mathcal{S}$ must be on one commom circle $\mathcal{C}$?

If it is the case, then it is not difficult to show $\mathcal{S}$ must consists of antipodal pairs of points with at most one point without diametrically opposed point.

**Question 2**: Can we classify finite right-triangle convex sets $\mathcal{S}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ provided that $\mathcal{S}$ is large enough? (Question 1 is a subcase of Question 2).

It seems that this problem is related to the problems about [repeated angles in planes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659290094B) in combinatorial geometry, but they are not exactly the same. And it is reasonable to ask Questions 1&2 for any field instead of $\mathbb{R}$.